# Determining if a Relation is a Partial Order

Tags: combinatorics, relations

Consider the following relation on all pairs of real numbers $(x, y): (x, y) \preccurlyeq (x′, y′)$ if $x ≤ 0$ and $y ≤ y′$. Is it a partial order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Check the reflexivity for $(1,0)$.

Comment: So just, x > 0 means that the partial ordering does not hold which conflicts with reflexivity?

Comment: Exactly. $(1,0) \not \preccurlyeq (1,0)$, so $\preccurlyeq$ is not reflexive and hence no partial order.